# Basic Types in C: legal way to write the number 65 assuming ASCII character set

Tags: c, types

I was reading *K.N.King's C Programming: A modern Approach* and stumble upon this question on Basic Types.

Here's the original question:
***Which one of the following is not a legal way to write the number 65? (Assume that the character set is ASCII.)***

*(a) 'A'*

*(b) 0b1000001*

*(C) 0101*

*(d) 0x41*

All four options seem legal to me and I was able to print the number '65' as such:

```
        char a, b, c, d;
        a = 'A';
        b = 0b1000001;
        c = 0101;
        d = 0x41;
        printf("%d\n", a);
        printf("%d\n", b);
        printf("%d\n", c);
        printf("%d\n", d);
```

The output:

```
65
65
65
65
```

What is the right answer then?

Comment: I feel like binary literals are a gcc extension and not standard C.

Comment: “Legal” is the wrong term. All are allowed by the C standard. (a), (C), and (d) are specified to work by the C standard (assuming ASCII for (a)). (b) is not specified to work. Nor is it specified not to work. Using it in a conforming C implementation requires a diagnostic message since it violates the constraint in C 2018 6.4 2, but the implementation may nonetheless accept it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil By "legal", I suspect "strictly-conforming C" was meant.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I am quite aware of how people use terms, albeit incorrectly. A problem with using “legal” to mean “strictly conforming” is that it would mean there are essentially no legal C programs in commerce. Any program that calls an operating system routine would not be legal. Any program that calls a graphics routine would not be legal. Any program that calls a routine written in another language would not be legal. That is not what people mean by “legal”; they generally do not want to exclude those things. So it does not mean “strictly conforming.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all four examples in my C interpreter:

```
ci> 'A'
65
ci> 0101
65
ci> 0x41
65
ci> 0b1000001
ci: error: Syntax error
ci>
```

Now, on the one hand, this `ci` is not a robust, modern, conforming C implementation.  But on the other hand, just like the C standard, it has never heard of `0b` constants, which are a useful but nonstandard extension.